# Ubuntu 23.04 can't save maximized window settings after closing applications

Tags: 23.04, maximized

I have a problem saving maximized window settings in Ubuntu 23.04 with applications when they're closed and then reopened. For example if I open Filezilla and maximize it, then after closing and reopening it again I have got Filezilla unmaximized.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue in thunderbird.

Comment: it's most likely a bug in mutter, please have a look here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2579